# Were scientific discoveries ever inspired by art?

Tags: physics, chemistry, biology

We can often see art that is influenced by science, be it in paintings, music, novels or movies. But has any idea from the arts ever influenced a scientist to come up with a new discovery or idea?

Comment: Related question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7292/229 where the "art" is a science fiction story.

Comment: An example from maths is that projective geometry is rooted in the use of perspective in art.  See the [history section of projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry#History) and links.

Answer (score 3):

It is plausible, albeit not proved, that [cubism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubism) provided some inspiration for quantum mechanics.  [Arthur Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_I._Miller) argued strongly that cubism helped [Niels Bohr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Bohr) develop the [complementarity principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_(physics)) in quantum mechanics. Bohr had read the book by [Jean Metzinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Metzinger) and [Albert Gleizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Gleizes) on cubist theory, ["Du Cubisme"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_%22Cubisme%22%22), and later had Metzinger's painting ["La Femme au Cheval"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Femme_au_Cheval#Influence_on_quantum_mechanics) in his office. See [Schinckus](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10699-016-9494-7) for a recent discussion of Miller's claim.

Materials science and engineering is one area where there is a small but steady stream of research inspired by historical art. The two- and three-dimensional patterns and shapes in this art can have interesting and useful structural properties. Here are a few examples:

- ["Between Science and Art: Thin Sound Absorbers Inspired by Slavic Ornaments"](https://doi.org/10.3389/fmats.2019.00182).
- ["Hybrid Nanogels-Based Printable Tattoos Inspired by Lady Costume from Tang Dynasty for Monitoring Solar UV Radiation"](https://doi.org/10.1002/adom.202202248)
- ["Writable and patternable organic solar cells and modules inspired by an old Chinese calligraphy tradition"](https://doi.org/10.1039/C7MH00559H)
- ["Bistable auxetic mechanical metamaterials inspired by ancient geometric motifs"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eml.2016.09.001)
- ["Kirigami Design and Modeling for Strong, Lightweight Metamaterials"](https://doi.org/10.1002/adfm.202107401)

Another related example is how Nobel-prize winning chemist [Harry Kroto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Kroto)'s familiarity with [Buckminster Fuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminster_Fuller)'s [geodesic domes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome) helped him [figure out](https://www.acs.org/content/dam/acsorg/education/whatischemistry/landmarks/lesson-plans/discovery-of-fullerenes.pdf) the structure of [C-60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene).

Of course, the most obvious possible source of artistic inspiration for science is *science fiction* in both books and film.
H.G. Wells [inspired](https://www.vqronline.org/essay/hg-wells-and-scientific-imagination) several leading scientists.  [Leo Szilard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Szilard) [implied](https://library.ucsd.edu/dc/object/bb58377715/_1.pdf) that H.G. Wells ["The World Set Free"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Set_Free) provided at least background inspiration for his work on the neutron chain reaction.
Wells also inspired [Robert Goddard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_H._Goddard), who in 1932 wrote to Wells [saying](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/bolden_goddard_2016.pdf)

> In 1898 I read your War of the Worlds. I was sixteen years old … and I decided that what might conservatively be called ‘high-altitude research’ was the most fascinating problem in existence. The spell did not break, and I took up physics ...